# Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file'

Tags: php, smarty

В логи пишется такая ошибка:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 
'Unable to load template file 'aboutcity.tpl'
```

Smarty подключен таким образом:

```
define('SMARTY_TPL','/style/'.$setup['skin'].'/');
require_once('smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->caching = true;
$smarty->template_dir = SMARTY_TPL.'templates/';
$smarty->compile_dir = SMARTY_TPL.'templates_c/';
$smarty->config_dir = SMARTY_TPL.'configs/';
$smarty->cache_dir = SMARTY_TPL.'cache/';
```

`$setup['skin']` равен `default`, берется из бд.

В коде файла где должен выводится шаблон пишу `$smarty->display('aboutcity.tpl');` и выводится белая страница (также она обрезается). Если убираю код `$smarty->display('aboutcity.tpl');`, то шаблон соответственно не выводится, но страница не обрезается. Права на папки - 0777. Что-то не пойму в чем проблема. Smarty только начал использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define('SMARTY_TPL', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/style/'.$setup['skin'].'/');
```

Или что у вас там за путь к папке с сайтом отвечает.  И проверяйте, что в переменных, прежде чем спрашивать) Плюс есть функция `file_exists`, например, если сомневаетесь.

Comment: Да уже решил проблему. Действительно этого $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].' не хватало.